# react component hover on children affect parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, css, ecmascript-6

I have this component structure

```
const Marker = props => (
  <Wrap>
    <Caret>
      <Container>$1000</Container>
    </Caret>
  </Wrap>
);
```

Where Caret have to be grey of Container got hovered. The problem is Caret isn't the children of container. How to have the entire marker have the same color when hovered?

Demo https://codesandbox.io/s/7j6n8v23m6

Comment: Can you please be more specific? I do not really understand the problem. If I understand correctly you can achieve what you want adding a hover on Wrap.

Comment: @Nubzor hover the marker, the background of everything should apply to grey

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to achieve your desired effect without use of triangleShadow component, instead I have used your styles and set them directly on marker style div. From here I've targeted pseudo after element.

```
  const Container = styled.div`
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  border: 3px solid #f48420;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;

  &:hover {
    background: #eee;
    &:after {
      border: 0.5em solid #eee;
    }
  }

  &:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    margin-left: -0.7em;
    bottom: -0.8em;
    left: 50%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 0.5em solid white;
    transform-origin: 0 0;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    box-shadow: -2px 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  }
`;
```

heres working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/pk23o04opj

Best of luck